# Start ngrok via systemctl services on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemctl

I am running a Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 and trying to run ngrok at startup using systemd, to create a ssh tunnel.

Current state:

- BWS_ngrok.service under /etc/systemd/system/BWS_ngrok.service
- ngrok.yml under /home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml
- ngrok path: /snap/bin/ngrok (according to `which ngrok`)

/etc/systemd/system/BWS_ngrok.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Ngrok at boot
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/snap/bin/ngrok start --config /home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml:

```
authtoken: <Ngrok-Authtoken>
tunnels:
  ssh:
    proto: tcp
    addr: 22
```

What I have done in the console:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl restart BWS_ngrok.service
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status
```

Output of `sudo systemctl status BWS_ngrok.service`:

```
BWS_ngrok.service
× BWS_ngrok.service - Start Ngrok at boot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/BWS_ngrok.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-09-13 19:27:11 UTC; 2s ago
    Process: 4734 ExecStart=/snap/bin/ngrok start --config /home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 4734 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 239ms

Sep 13 19:27:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Start Ngrok at boot.
Sep 13 19:27:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: BWS_ngrok.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 13 19:27:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: BWS_ngrok.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What I have tried so far:

- In the `.service` file: `ExecStart=/snap/bin/ngrok tcp 22` (Added the Ngrok-Authtoken before with `ngrok config add-authtoken <Ngrok-Authtoken>`)
- Checking the location of the config file of ngrok with `ngrok config check`, which gave me `Valid configuration file at /home/ubuntu/snap/ngrok/85/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml`, so I added the following in this file:

```
authtoken: <Ngrok-Authtoken>
tunnels:
  ssh:
    proto: tcp
    addr: 22
```

If I try to print out the journalctl log, as Edgar Magallon said, I get the following:

```
Nov 19 16:05:34 bws systemd[1]: Started Start Ngrok at boot.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit BWS_ngrok.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit BWS_ngrok.service has finished successfully.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 29439.
Nov 19 16:05:34 bws systemd[1]: BWS_ngrok.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit BWS_ngrok.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Nov 19 16:05:34 bws systemd[1]: BWS_ngrok.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit BWS_ngrok.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
```

That is the same as the systemctl status output, so no additional information...

But I still have not managed to get Ngrok to start at boot.

Comment: You can get a more detailed log about the error by using `sudo journalctl -xu  BWS_ngrok.service`. Sometimes the logs displayed by `systemctl status` are not enough to know what is actually happening.

Comment: I get the same Output there. I am going to edit the question to include the journalctl output

Comment: It seems the problem is with `ngrok`: *"An ExecStart= process belonging to unit BWS_ngrok.service has exited."*

Comment: Try running directly in the terminal: `/snap/bin/ngrok start --config /home/ubuntu/server/bwsv4/ngrok.yml`

Comment: Btw, I believe the problem might be with snap, because this one uses systemd to start as far as I know. So your ngrok service could be running before snap service has started.

Comment: Not sure if the snap service is: `snapd.service`. You can try adding this to `After` option: `After=network-online.target snapd.service`

Comment: I've edited the ExecStart to run ```/snap/bin/ngrok start ssh```, which i have tested in the terminal and it works. For that I have edited the config file which is shown when i run ```ngrok config check```. The part with snap sounds good, but also with it, it does not work. What should I try next?

Comment: That's really weird. 1) Have you tried running `ngrok` without `snap`? You can try to install `ngrok` via `apt`.

Comment: 2) Given that you are not getting any useful log try adding these lines in `[Service]` section (inside BWS_ngrok.service): `StandardOutput=file:/home/ubuntu/ngrokSdtout` `StandardError=file:/home/ubuntu/scriptStderr`

Comment: When you run the service or this runs at boot, check the logs by using `cat /home/ubuntu/ngrokSdtout` and `cat /home/ubuntu/scriptStderr`.  About `StandardOutput=file:/path/` and `StandardError=file:/path` make sure you are running a systemd version 236 or newer. I guess you are actually running an updated version given that you are using `Ubuntu 22`

Comment: Thank you very much, installing ngrok vie apt did the magic.

Comment: Glad this worked for you! So the problem was actually the snap. It's still better using apt than snap for some packages.